# Deny creation of publically accessible GCP buckets at project level?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-bucket

How to deny the creation of public accessible GCP buckets using Organization policies using at the project level using policies?

Also, how could I provide exemptions for Organization policies?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information , what do you mean by public GCP bucket ? Do you mean denying public access to the bucket?

Comment: yes, correct. I want to deny the creation of publically accessible GCP buckets at project level.

Comment: Have you checked this [document-1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access), the Uniform bucket-level access inherits bucket ACLs from the project-level IAM permissions. Fine-grained (or ACL) access controls do not inherit project-level IAM permissions for storage objects, instead each storage object requires its own specific set of ACLs. 
With Fine grained access controls, ACLs can be managed at the bucket level and overridden per object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case I would suggest applying permissions using "fine-grained" method, but you can only set the permissions at both the bucket level and per individual object, please check document[1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) and document[2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) for the details.